# Micropython Rapsberry Pico "no module named ffi" on ssd1306 lib

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Im new here :)
I bought the Rapsberry Pico with the lcd screen, i want to display something on this display but when i import ssd1306 lib Thonny send me a problem "no module named ffi" i don't know how to import this lib.
Thats my simple code:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
import ssd1306

i2c = I2C(scl=Pin(1), sda=Pin(0), freq=400000)
display = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)
display.text("some text", 0, 0)
display.show()
```

I installed micropython-ssd1306 lib before ofc.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "ssd1306.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/lib/framebuf.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/lib/usdl2.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'ffi'
```

MicroPython v1.13-395-gcb04da56d on 2021-01-12; Raspberry Pi Pico with RP2040

Comment: Where is the code running - is this on the Raspberry Pi Pico itself, or on your computer?

Comment: On Rapbsberry Pico

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the full error traceback?

Comment: I'm struggling to reproduce this with MicroPython 1.18 on an RP2040 (Pico) board. Can you provide more information? The traceback and versions etc.

Comment: I updated 1st post

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking at the source tree, the `ffi` module is only supported on the Unix port.

Comment: That (`ffi` / Unix) is why I asked to confirm that this was being run on the Pico rather than on the host. It's an older build of MicroPython - I'm running 1.18 here and I don't get that error. Would you be able to update to a more recent build?

Comment: Thanks guys! Update micropython to 1.18 has solved my problem. :)